# How do I access all the elements of a data.frame using group_by (dplyr)?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose we have a data.frame 'df':

```
 speed dist lan
      4    2 "bra"
      4   10 "bra"
      7    4 "bra"
      7   22 "col"
      8   16 "col"
      9   10 "col"
     10   18 "fin"
             ...
```

I want to realize some operations on speed and dist groupin_by lan, for example, to try to print some values.
How do I do that?

I've tried this manner but I cannot achieve success:

```
df %>%
  group_by(lan) %>%
  (function(.) {
      print(.$speed)
      print(.$dist)
  })
```

Comment: Do you want to change the variables or summarize?

Comment: Neither one. I don't want to change the data.frame. I just want to print or execute other functions...

Comment: What is the output you expect? Please add that to the question.

Comment: If you just want to print one column in the order of another, I think you can `arrange` instead of `group_by`.

Comment: Look at `dplyr::do`, namely something like `df %>% group_by(lab) %>% do(ign={ print(.$speed); print(.$dist); })`. (The `ign=` is kind of necessary, otherwise `dplyr` expects the code block to return a data.frame. This work only as long as you are really ignoring the results of the code block!)

Comment: thanks, @r2evans. It's just what i wanted to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `do` as @r2evans suggested in the comments above. But it is usually better to just return the original `data.frame`, so you can continue to work with it. In your case for instance you might want to calculate the mean speed and mean dist after:

```
df %>%
  group_by(lan) %>%
  do({
    cat("lan = ", .$lan[1], "\n")
    print(.$speed)
    print(.$dist)
    .
  }) %>% 
  summarise(mean(speed), mean(dist))
```

And just so I can show the output, here's an example with `mtcars`.

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  do({cat("cyl = ", .$cyl[1], "\n")
      print(.$mpg) 
      print(.$wt) 
      .}) %>% 
  summarise(mean(mpg), mean(wt))
## cyl =  4 
##  [1] 22.8 24.4 22.8 32.4 30.4 33.9 21.5 27.3 26.0 30.4 21.4
##  [1] 2.320 3.190 3.150 2.200 1.615 1.835 2.465 1.935 2.140 1.513 2.780
## cyl =  6 
## [1] 21.0 21.0 21.4 18.1 19.2 17.8 19.7
## [1] 2.620 2.875 3.215 3.460 3.440 3.440 2.770
## cyl =  8 
##  [1] 18.7 14.3 16.4 17.3 15.2 10.4 10.4 14.7 15.5 15.2 13.3 19.2 15.8  15.0
##  [1] 3.440 3.570 4.070 3.730 3.780 5.250 5.424 5.345 3.520 3.435 3.840 3.845 3.170 3.570
## Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
## 
##   cyl mean(mpg) mean(wt)
## 1   4  26.66364 2.285727
## 2   6  19.74286 3.117143
## 3   8  15.10000 3.999214
```